# UIButton not select the correct cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

in my tableview I have a button in the custom cell

I used the delegates to take an action to the button

The button image changes only on the selected cell

My problem is this:

When I press the button happens:

- the selected cell is working properly and the button changes correctly (correct)
- the second immediately after the selected cell does not change the button (corrected)
- the third cell repeats the action of the selected cell (wrong)

This is repeated endlessly do not understand why 
 The button should change only the selected cell and not on other non-selected

Can you help me please?

```
-(void)ButtonPressedGoPoint:(FFCustomCellWithImage *)custom button:(UIButton *)gopointpressed {


    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"it_IT"]];
    NSNumber *likeCount = [numberFormatter numberFromString:custom.CountGoPoint.text];

    if (!custom.AddGoPoint.selected) {
        NSLog(@"TastoSelezionato");
        likeCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[likeCount intValue] + 1];
        custom.CountGoPoint.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", likeCount];

       [custom.AddGoPoint setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FFIMG_Medal_Blu"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    else  {
        if ([likeCount intValue] > 0) {
            likeCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[likeCount intValue] - 1];
            custom.CountGoPoint.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", likeCount];
        }

        NSLog(@"TastoDeselezionato");
       [custom.AddGoPoint setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FFIMG_MedalADD"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }

    custom.AddGoPoint.selected = !custom.AddGoPoint.selected;


}
```

This is my implementation of the tableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    self.PostDetails = [ArrayforPost objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    static NSString *IdentificazioneCellaIMG = @"CellaIMG";
        FFCustomCellWithImage * CellaIMG = (FFCustomCellWithImage * )[self.FFTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:IdentificazioneCellaIMG];
        if (CellaIMG == nil) {
            CellaIMG = [[FFCustomCellWithImage alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:IdentificazioneCellaIMG ];
        }

        CellaIMG.delegate = self;

     CellaIMG.tag = indexPath.row;
       [CellaIMG.AddGoPoint setTag:indexPath.row];

        if ([self AssignedGoPointToPost:self.PostDetails]) {
            CellaIMG.AddGoPoint.selected =YES;
             [CellaIMG.AddGoPoint setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FFIMG_Medal_Blu"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        } else {
            CellaIMG.AddGoPoint.selected =NO;
             [CellaIMG.AddGoPoint setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FFIMG_MedalADD"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }

        NSString *FotoPostSocial = [self.PostDetails objectForKey:FF_POST_IMMAGINE];
        CellaIMG.FotoPost.file = (PFFile *)FotoPostSocial;
        [CellaIMG.FotoPost loadInBackground];
        CellaIMG.FotoPost.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        CellaIMG.FotoPost.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0f;
        CellaIMG.FotoPost.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

        CellaIMG.backgroundCell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        CellaIMG.backgroundCell.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0f;
        CellaIMG.backgroundCell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(219/255.0) green:(219/255.0) blue:(219/255.0) alpha:(1)].CGColor;
        CellaIMG.backgroundCell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
        CellaIMG.backgroundCell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        CellaIMG.LeggiCommentoButton.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0f;
        CellaIMG.FotoProfilo.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        CellaIMG.FotoProfilo.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0f;
        CellaIMG.FotoProfilo.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

        CellaIMG.TestoPost.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0f];
        NSString *text = [self.PostDetails objectForKey:FF_POST_TEXT];
        CellaIMG.TestoPost.text = text;
        [CellaIMG.TestoPost setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
        NSString *NomeUser = [[self.PostDetails objectForKey:FF_POST_UTENTE] objectForKey:FF_USER_NOMECOGNOME];
        CellaIMG.NomeUtente.text = NomeUser;
        NSString *ImmagineUtente = [[self.PostDetails objectForKey:FF_POST_UTENTE] objectForKey:FF_USER_FOTOPROFILO];
        CellaIMG.FotoProfilo.file = (PFFile *)ImmagineUtente;
        [CellaIMG.FotoProfilo loadInBackground];

        if (CellaSelezionata == indexPath.row) {
            CGFloat AltezzaLabel = [self valoreAltezzaCella: indexPath.row];
            CellaIMG.TestoPost.frame = CGRectMake(CellaIMG.TestoPost.frame.origin.x, CellaIMG.TestoPost.frame.origin.y, CellaIMG.TestoPost.frame.size.width, AltezzaLabel);  }

        else {
            CellaIMG.TestoPost.frame = CGRectMake(CellaIMG.TestoPost.frame.origin.x, CellaIMG.TestoPost.frame.origin.y, CellaIMG.TestoPost.frame.size.width, 65);
        }

        return CellaIMG;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in the tableview datasource

Comment: thanks to reply Rich, i'm edited my post